# making sure my loop is completely finished before running a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexslider

I have created a loop that templates my data and then appends it into a selected div, I want to make sure that this data has been completely templated and injected before I run my next function so what I really need is something like a callback function. Can anyone advise how I might do this?

JS

```
// Template slideshow
for (var i = 0, len = data.films.length; i < len; i++) {
    var dataPath = data.films[i];
    var tmp = '<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300/000/' + dataPath.id + '" /><h2>' + dataPath.title + '</h2></li>';

    $('.slides').append(tmp);
}

// Want to run this once Im sure all data has been templated and injected
$('.flexslider').flexslider({
    animation: "slide"
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a callback. The code that you have created is always injected by the time the loop completes.

Comment: oh, i didnt think this would be the case thats why i wanted to cover myself

Answer (score 1):

```
// Template slideshow
for (var i = 0, len = data.films.length; i < len; i++) {
    var dataPath = data.films[i];
    var tmp = '<li><img src="http://dummyimage.com/300/000/' + dataPath.id + '" /><h2>' + dataPath.title + '</h2></li>';

    $('.slides').append(tmp);

    // Want to run this once Im sure all data has been templated and injected
    if (i==len) {
       $('.flexslider').flexslider({
          animation: "slide"
       });​
    }
}
```

Comment: Inside the loop `i` is always smaller than `len`, so that will just keep the code from running at all.

Comment: you are fast - realized the error immediately and corrected it, but :-)